# Graphs prove question

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every graph in which each vertex has degree at least 2 must contain a cycle.

I know that for Hand Shaking Theorem: each edge is responsible for 2 degrees in a graph. But how do I prove each vertex that has degree at least 2 must contain a cycle? Can anyone show me how to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true for infinite graphs, nor for empty graphs.

But in a finite non-empty graph start at a vertex, and keep walking, without doubling back on the edge you've just walked along.
Eventually you will hit a vertex you've met below, and bingo, a cycle!

Comment: but i thought it asked "prove that EVERY GRAPH..............must contain a cycle". Doesn't it mean that every graph will be true?

Comment: @maths infinite binary tree has no cycles.

Comment: @DavidPeterson Ok, thanks!

Comment: @maths It depends how how you define the word *graph*. I find that most of the time, a graph is implied to be finite and nonempty.